# Log4j used in multithread project

Tags: multithreading, log4j

If I use log4j in a multithread project, is it possible to have race condition?
When all threads trying to access that logger?

If there's no race condition, does log4j provide some mechanism to avoid that?

Thank you very much:)

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a1.7  And, of course, https://www.google.com/search?q=log4j+thread+safe

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is just one instance of logger object, so the race condition may be on a log target in case of target not being able to handle that e.g. A file sysytem.